What is this IC marked "210"?
Can everybody help me find this IC marked " 210"


This SOIC-4 device is a Panasonic AQY210S. It is a MOSFET optocoupler. I found the part by going on Google and searching "SOIC-4 210" and it found it Google Images as one of the first results.

Picture found here. The picture is a slightly different variant that is an AQY210EHA.

I think it is AQY210S

@HNLinh That would be a good assumption because in its datasheet, it does mention: Note: For space reasons, the three initial letters of the part number “AQY”, the package (SOP) indicator “S” and the packing style indicator “X” are not marked on the device. (Ex. the label for product number AQY210SX is 210.)
